# Length of a curve is independent of the parameterization

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Given a vector space $V$, and a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on it, *being absolutely homogeneous* is one of the properties of the norm. How to show that this condition is necessary and sufficient for the fact that

**the length of a regular curve is independent of the choice of parameter**

P.S. By absolutely homogeneous we mean $\|rv\|=\|r\|\cdot\|v\|$ where $v\in V$ and $r$ is an element of the field over which we define the vector space.

Comment: What is the definition of "absolutely homogenous norm"?

Comment: @uniquesolution That is $||rv||=|r|.||v||$ where $v\in V$ and $r$ is an element of the field over which we define the vector space.

Comment: in that case, there is no need to mention this as a "property of the norm", because it is part of the definition of a norm.

Comment: Yes! My point is that how using this property of the norm one can prove that the length is not dependent of the reparametrizations.